# Jquery syntax and event binding

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to bind an onclick event when I generate the HTML. I am attempting to use the object ID to bind the event using the for each method.

I am not sure what the syntax error is and would like some help spotting/troubleshooting this. I recieved the "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and I have marked the line where this occurs in the code comments

```js
var LIST2 = [];
var coreUrl = "https://cors.io/?http://rundistance.azurewebsites.net/api/";
var listUrl = coreUrl + "RunnerService";

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON(listUrl).done(function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, item)
        {
            LIST2.push(item);
            displayList();
        });
    });

    function displayList()
    {
        $("table#itemlist2").empty();

        $.each(LIST2, function(index, value)
        {
            $("table#itemlist2").append(
                '<tr id =' + index + '><td>' + value.RunnerName +
                '</td><td><a class="delete" alt="delete" href="#">DELETE</a> <a class="details" alt="details" href="#">Details</a></td></tr>'

            // Code bug is here, Is this in relation to the string 
            // above or am I nesting my function incorrectly?

            $(index).click(function()
            {
                console.log("you click" + index);
            });
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to close your document.ready invocation and the function within it. You're missing `});` at the end of the code.

Comment: I literally jsut realised that about 30 seconds after I posted it. Thanks will mark as resolved.

Comment: This issue is more obvious when you format your code correctly, as I've edited for you now. I'd suggest looking in to using an IDE which does this automatically when you save.

Comment: Also note that you could make the code simpler by using a delegated event handler instead of binding multiple events as the elements are added to the DOM. This would also remove the need for global variables, which should always be avoided where at all possible.

Comment: I will look into this now Rory, for now I have my indexes which is what I was after at this stage.

Comment: You have some closing function problems: **1)** $(document).ready() should be closed like this **});**, not this **}**. **2)** you have not closed method append(), you forgot to include the **);** at the end of the line. **3)** the each loop is also wrong closed, should be like **});** not this **);**. And **4)** displayList() method should be closed like **}**, not this: **});**.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct sintax..

```
var LIST2 = [];
var coreUrl = "https://cors.io/?http://rundistance.azurewebsites.net/api/";
var listUrl = coreUrl + "RunnerService";
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $.getJSON(listUrl)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    LIST2.push(item);
                    displayList();
                });
     });

    function displayList()
    {
        $("table#itemlist2").empty();
        $.each(LIST2, function (index, value) {
            $("table#itemlist2").append(
                '<tr id =' + index + '><td>' + value.RunnerName +'</td><td><a class="delete" alt="delete" href="#">DELETE</a> <a class="details" alt="details" href="#">Details</a></td></tr>'
              //Code bug is here, Is this in relation to the string 
              // above or am I nesting my function incorrectly?

                );
                 $('#'+ index).click(function(){
                      console.log("you click" + index);
                    });
            });
        }
   })
```

As you can see the event is binded to the object outside of the .append function.